# How do I minimize the difference between development and production data after normalization relative to measures of central tendency?

Tags: sampling, normalization, central-tendency

I think that normalization of data is performed assuming that the samples you train on are "representative" of real-world or "production" data. This means I have to constantly monitor the performance and data of my model after deployment. If I normalize using z-scores or mean data, a non-representative sample will give me results skewed in an unpredictable direction. I might need to run clustering algorithms on training and production data. I could also check the differences per feature between production and training data and watch for significant differences. Aside from getting a large and representative sample of my target data, how do I preemptively stop skewed data after normalizing relative to a central tendency value? If you think a good sample selection is the only way, feel free to explain why and how I might find a representative sample.